# Why do class_respondsToSelector and respondsToSelector behave different when sent to Class?

Tags: objective-c, selector, objective-c-runtime

I have spent quite some time trying to figure out how `class_respondsToSelector` and `respondsToSelector` can give different results. Consider the following class:

```
@interface Dummy : NSObject
- (void)test;
@end

@implementation Dummy
- (void)test {}
@end
```

My scenario is that I try to determine if a class responds to a certain class method. This piece reproduces the problem:

```
Class class = [Dummy class];
if (class_respondsToSelector(class, @selector(test)))
    NSLog(@"class_respondsToSelector: YES");
else
    NSLog(@"class_respondsToSelector: NO");
if ([class respondsToSelector:@selector(test)])
    NSLog(@"respondsToSelector: YES");
else
    NSLog(@"respondsToSelector: NO");
```

If I remove the declaration and implementation of `-test`, the output of the above is NO and NO as expected. However, running it as it reads above (including `-test`), the output produced is the following:

> class_respondsToSelector: YES
>
> respondsToSelector: NO

The documentation says nothing about whether `respondsToSelector` works for instances only, just that it *indicates whether the receiver implements...*, hence I am unable to determine whether this is correct behavior or not. Am I missing something?

**Update**

Graham Lee provided this link to a [great discussion on the problem](http://www.mentby.com/Group/objc-language/classrespondstoselector-fails-thought-the-class-does-respond-to-the-selector.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question asked by `class_respondsToSelector()` is "Do instances of this class respond to this selector?"

The question asked by `-[NSObject respondsToSelector:]` is "Does this particular instance (which is the "reciever") respond to this selector?"

You're sending `respondsToSelector:` to a class object, which is itself an instance of its metaclass, and asking about that particular object.

To see the same results as `class_respondsToSelector()`, either use `+[NSObject instancesRespondToSelector:]` or get an instance of the class.